# Eclipse "CDT Core Builder" error

Tags: compile, eclipse

I installed an Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0) for Arduino.

I’ve got an `CDT Core Builder error`  when I try to compile.

I’ve searched but cannot fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: It is strange, because I added AVR Eclipse Plugin and GNU AVR-GCC toolchain.
Also creating new project C/C++ -> Arduino Project. According some sources it works. But mine shows CDT error.

Comment: I have no clue what you installed. If you want to make arduino in eclipse easy use my sloeber at sloeber.io